# how to have a lock on a mysql database and dequeue the waiting jobs

Tags: mysql, locking, persistence, deque

i was wondering if anyone knew how to lock a database, and then dequeue the waiting jobs. so i have a hashtable in a database, and im storing data in the database where multiple users are sending requests to edit that data at the same time, but the data needs to be persistent across all users and that only one user can acesss/edit it at a time.

thanks a bunch = )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find something interesting at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html. One technique for serializing transactions is to create a table with just one row in it, and have every transaction update this row before commencing its real work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on "but the data needs to be persistent across all users"?

I think that InnoDb which is transactional will keep things in a way that's consistent to all of your users. It's [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) compliant.